C++ variadic template with values instead of typenames
In C++, is there some equivalent of variadic template with values instead of typename or class?
Inside a method of a template class, the idea is to use values which are specified in the declaration of the instance, without going through a constructor.
That could be something like that (correct syntax not yet found):
template <class T, "some variadic value syntax...">
class Sample
{
public:
    T val() { return T("some variadic value syntax..."); }
};

Sample <std::string> a;            // a.val() returns ""
Sample <std::string, "foo"> b;     // b.val() returns "foo"
Sample <std::string, 4, 'a'> c;    // c.val() returns "aaaa"

Currently, the equivalent is done with preprocessing macros that I would like to eradicate and replace with templates.
Any other idea is welcome, as long as:

it does not use macros,
it uses up to C++17 but not more recent,
there is no need to pass the values to a constructor,
we don't store the values inside the object instance,
the constructor of the object may not have been called yet (static object inside a not-yet-initialized module),
allow any number of values, including zero.


Use template <class T, auto...>. Working demo. Note that you can't pass string literal "foo" as template argument.

what kind of values do you think of ? Simple types (like int) are ok but litteral strings should be a problem.

As a workaround for the string literal case, you can use user defined literal. It is trivial and left as an exercise.

Thanks, the problem is exactly the one you mention : need to pass any expression which is acceptable in the T(...) constructor call. Simple int types is not enough.

Generically the answer to the question is no.  Non-type template parameters are limited to structural types.  If you want to support any type then you need something else.

what is wrong with constexpr and std::string_view? Why do you need string literal as template parameter? What is actual goal? Or you are trying to just satisfy language features curiosity?

search for C++ NTTP

@Red.Wave : If you read correctly, C++ NTTP is the question (how to use them in that case), not the answer

@ThierryLelegard I didn't see that keyword in question. I couldn't confirm if you even knew about the idea, because of the composure of your question.

This syntax isn't viable, because most types can't be template parameters. Among other things, you can't pass string literals (there are workarounds, but they don't work for your case).
The only viable solution is to pass a functor, e.g. a lambda:
template <class T, auto F>
class Sample
{
public:
    T val() { return F(); }
};

Sample<std::string, []{return std::string{};}> a;          // a.val() returns ""
Sample<std::string, []{return std::string("foo");}> b;     // b.val() returns "foo"
Sample<std::string, []{return std::string(4, 'a');}> c;    // c.val() returns "aaaa"

But this requires C++20. Pre-C++20 you'd have to replace lambdas with functions (or functor classes), so the syntax wouldn't look as good.

You can use the placeholder type auto as shown below. Note that string literals are not allowed to be template arguments in current c++. So the second example Sample <std::string, "foo"> b;  will never work because here "foo" cannot be passed. You can use user defined literals as a workaround for that.
template <class T, auto...Vs>
class Sample
{
public:
    T val() { return T(Vs...); }
};


@ThierryLelegard The answer is based on the given question and it answers the question. For your follow up question feel free to ask a new question.
